# Converting temperature to int

Tags: python, selenium

I am using selenium to find a web element on a website that shows the temperature in this format "39 c". Is there anyway to convert that into int so I could use operators like <,=>,<, etc?

```
temperature = driver.find_element(By.ID, "temperature")
temperature = int(float(temperature.text))



if temperature < 19:
    driver.find_element_by_link_text('Buy sunscreens').click()
elif temperature > 34:
    driver.find_element_by_link_text('Buy moisturizers').click();
```

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '9 ℃'

Answer (score 0):

You could use `str.split`:

```
temperature = int(temperature.text.split()[0])
```

Or use `re`:

```
temperature = int(re.search('\d+', temperature.text)[0])
```

Comment: This worked for me. I appreciate the help. Would upvote but brand new account.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string based on spaces, and then can call `int` on it.

```
temperature = driver.find_element(By.ID, "temperature")
temperature_int = int(temperature.text.split(' ')[0])
print(type(temperature_int))
print(temperature_int)
```